# ANSI C - count the size of the string pointer

Tags: c

Is it possible to create string variables using pointers? So that I don't have to pass its size everytime, like char x[4] = "aaa"?

How can I get the size of such string?

And can I initialize an empty string with a pointer?

Comment: Any chance you could clarify this a little?

Comment: When you say "pass its size" you mean as function parameters I assume?

Comment: 2 beers + a lot of cut and paste, lol, sorry, edited already :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember that strings in C are ended by the **null terminator** character, written as `\0`. If you have a well-formed string stored in your pointer variable, you can therefore determine the length by searching for this character:

```
char *x = "hello"; // automatically appends a null terminator
int len = 0;
while (x[len] != '\0') {
    len++;
}
```

If your variables are uninitialized or otherwise not well-formed (e.g., by being `NULL`) you obviously cannot take this approach; however, most functions are generally written under the assumption that the strings *are* well-formed, because this leads to faster code.

If you wish to initialize a pointer, you have three options: `NULL`, a valid address (e.g., `char *x = &someCharVar`), or a string constant (e.g., `char *x = "hello"`). Note that if you use a string constant, it is **illegal** for you to write into that pointer unless you re-assign to it with the address of a non-constant string.

```
// Get enough space for 24 characters plus null terminator
char *myString = (char*) malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(myString, "some text"); // fill the new memory
fgets(myString, 25, stdin); // fill with keyboard input
```

Note that `sizeof(char)` is unnecessary here, since a `char` is always defined to be exactly 1 byte. However, it's a good habit to get into for when you're using other data types, and it helps make your code self-documenting by making your intentions very clear.

Comment: Could you provide any example of such initialization with malloc?

Comment: +1 but better to add const: const char *x = "hello";  So you can't assign x dereferenced.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for that and for all advices.

Answer (score 3):

If you're initializing an array of `char` with a string literal, you don't need to specify the size:

```
char str[] = "This is a test";
```

This will create `str` as a 15-element array of `char` (the size is taken from the length of the initiliazer, including the 0 terminator) and copy the contents of the string literal to it.

A string literal is an *array expression* of type "N-element array of `char`" (`const char` in C++).  Except when it is being used to initialize an array in a declaration (such as above) or is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an expression of type "array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

If you write

```
const char *str = "This is a test";
```

the expression "This is a test" is converted from type "15-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first character, which is written to the variable `str`.

The behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined*; some platforms store string literals in read-only memory, some do not.  Some map multiple occurrences of the same string literal to a single instance, others don't.  It's best to always treat a string literal as unmodifiable, which is why I declared `str` as `const char *` instead of just `char *`.

To get the *length* of a string, use `strlen`:

```
char str[] = "This is a test"; // or const char *str = "This is a test";
size_t len = strlen(str);      // or strlen("This is a test");
```

This will return the number of characters in the string up to (but not including) the 0 terminator; `strlen("This is a test")` will return 14.

To get the size of the buffer containing the string, you would use the `sizeof` operator:

```
char str[] = "This is a test";
size_t len = sizeof str;       // or sizeof "This is a test"
```

Note that this *won't* give you the size of the buffer if you declared `str` as a pointer, such as

```
const char *str = "This is a test";
```

In that case, `sizeof str;` only gives you the size of a `char *`, not the string it points to.